# How to test the label of an input on angular 4+?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a angular component with a form like this:

```
<form>
  <label for="Name">Click me</label>
  <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" />

  <label for="Name2">Click me 2</label>
  <input type="text" id="Name2" name="Name" />

</form>
```

I need to have a unit test that validate that input[id=Name] have a label with text: "Click Name". How can I implement that unit test on angular with jasmin and karma?

Answer (score 3):

Get the element and test it.

```
it('should check label name', () => {
    let labelName = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("label[for=Name]"));
    expect(labelName.nativeElement.textContent).toBe("Click Me");
})
```

The question is how to interact with that element and not how to test it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is a bit confused.
Below a possible solution for test the label regardless an input or not.

**Import:**

> import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
>
> import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

**Code:**

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent> = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
const queryValue = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#your-label-id'));

expect(queryValue).toBeTruthy();
expect(queryValue.nativeElement).toBeTruthy();
expect(queryValue.nativeElement.outerText).toContain("Text expected in the label");
```